# Troubleshooting remote connection - is the my home network or my work network?

Tags: networking, router, ssh

I've set up port forwarding on my home router to forward ssh (port 22 - it actually came with a preset which is pretty cool) to my home laptop's ip, I also set up ftp (20~21, again preset).

When I try to ssh in, it hangs for a good few minutes before it times out.

A ping of just the home router IP gives `Destination unreachable : Address unreachable`.

FTP gives `connect: no route to host`, however I think I may have forgotten to change the IP from the default.

My home address is an ipv6 address.

What I'm mainly trying to figure out - is it my home network settings that are wrong, or is it the work network blocking traffic?

When I was at home, I tried to ping my home router (from its external IP) and it responded immediately. I didn't try to ssh/ftp.

Comment: Your work network could be blocking a lot of things, or not support IPv6. Can you use FTP or SSH on other addresses?

Comment: I can ftp/ssh within the work network no problem. I don't know of any remote places that would accept ftp/ssh to test with

Comment: Hard to find a public FTP site these days. Try ftp.ensembl.org. For SSH, try to SFTP to sftp.sdarchive.iu.edu (SFTP is a file transfer protocol over SSH). You can't fully connect without a pwd but you can easily check that you get the initial handshake.

Comment: Yup, I got into both of those. Looks like it's home-side. Thanks!